# Create UserControl on Parent Form from User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a Parent Form, on the press of a button, the following code runs:

```
UCDataSetSearch dataSetSearch = new UCDataSetSearch(formStorage.Schema, "Schema");
InitializeUserControl(dataSetSearch);
```

On this UserControl the user selected a DataSet and can then modify it by clicking the Modify button, however what is the correct way for on pressing that button in the UserControl it then creates a new instance of another UserControl on the parent form?

InitializeUserControl method just takes a User Control and adds it to the controls of the form and sets its Location to a specific point in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If `InitializeUserControl()` is a **Public** method on your Form, then you can call it directly utilizing [FindForm()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
// ... running from within the UserControl ...
// assuming Form1 is the parent form (change as necessary)
Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.FindForm(); 
UCDataSetSearch dataSetSearch = new UCDataSetSearch(formStorage.Schema, "Schema");
f1.InitializeUserControl(dataSetSearch);
```

This is a **tightly coupled** solution, which means your UserControl is now less re-usable as it can no longer work with other Forms.

A **loosely coupled** solution would have the UserControl raise a **Custom Event** to let the Form know it should add a new instance to itself.